# R function to copy from one connection to another

Tags: r

I want to write data that is in a file to an R connection.  I can do this using `readBin()` followed by `writeBin()`, but that's bad because the entire thing is temporarily in memory.  Is there a function to copy binary data from one connection to another, or do I need to write my own loop?  (Which makes me feel bad, this being R.)

Comment: If you modify the data, I imagine you'll need some kind of loop. If you don't, you could just copy the file

Comment: I am not modifying the data.  However I am writing to a network connection, so I cannot just copy the file.